# How to find selected format file using google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I was following the refference from google drive api v3 and trying to find the file name with format is *.capx*

here the api `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='FOLDER_ID'+in+parents&name='.capx'&pageSize=1000&fields=files(name,size,description,webContentLink,webViewLink,createdTime)&key=`

output

```
{
 "files": [
  {
   "name": "tes.zip",
   "webContentLink": "",
   "webViewLink": "",
   "createdTime": "",
   "size": ""
  },
{
   "name": "tes.capx",
   "webContentLink": "",
   "webViewLink": "",
   "createdTime": "",
   "size": ""
  }
 ]
}
```

I want output like this

```
{
 "files": [
{
   "name": "tes.capx",
   "webContentLink": "",
   "webViewLink": "",
   "createdTime": "",
   "size": ""
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the files which has the extension of `.capx` using the search query of the method of files.list in Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? In this answer, `'FOLDER_ID' in parents and name contains '.capx'` is used as the search query.

#### Modified endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&q='FOLDER_ID' in parents and name contains '.capx'&fields=files(name,size,description,webContentLink,webViewLink,createdTime)
```

or

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&q=%27FOLDER_ID%27%20in%20parents%20and%20name%20contains%20%27.capx%27&fields=files(name%2Csize%2Cdescription%2CwebContentLink%2CwebViewLink%2CcreatedTime)
```

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: it's works! thanks.
`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='FOLDER_ID'+in+parents+and+name+contains+'.capx'&pageSize=1000&fields=files(name,size,description,webContentLink,webViewLink,createdTime)&key=`

Comment: @b3253223b33v Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.